# Selecting from table when two fields satisfy OR condition. And if they satisfy AND condition on same fields select the ones with early date

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

```
ID1  ID2     DATE        INITIAL   FINAL
20   328    2016/11/08    01         01
21   328    2016/11/11    01         01
53   766    2016/09/26    00         01
39   766    2016/11/25    01         00
```

There are two entries for each ID2

In the above example I want to select records with INITIAL = 01 **or** FINAL = 01 but also when INITIAL = 01 **and** FINAL = 01 for same ID2, I want to select the one with earlier date

I am looking for a final set that looks like this

```
ID1  ID2     DATE        INITIAL   FINAL
20   328    2016/11/08    01         01
53   766    2016/09/26    00         01
39   766    2016/11/25    01         00
```

Answer (score 0):

in this example 'OR' includes 'AND'

try it

```
select * from (select  * from myTable where INITIAL = '01' or FINAL = '01' order by Date) where Rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat your 2 cases like separate queries then union them. The WITH is just me building dummy data. This will not address the case of an id2 having 01 initial and 01 final, and another row with 00 and 01 --- but that wasn't in your requirements. Nor will it address the issue if you have two 01 01 rows for the same id2 with the same min date, but again - that wasn't in the spec; I just wanted to state those things to be thorough.

```
with records as
  (select 20 as id1, 328 as id2, to_date('2016-11-08','YYYY-MM-DD') as mydate, '01' as myinitial, '01' as myfinal from dual
   union all
   select 21 as id1, 328 as id2, to_date('2016-11-11','YYYY-MM-DD') as mydate, '01' as myinitial, '01' as myfinal from dual
   union all
   select 53 as id1, 766 as id2, to_date('2016-09-26','YYYY-MM-DD') as mydate, '00' as myinitial, '01' as myfinal from dual
   union all
   select 39 as id1, 766 as id2, to_date('2016-11-25','YYYY-MM-DD') as mydate, '01' as myinitial, '00' as myfinal from dual)

select *
from records
where (myinitial = '01' or myfinal = '01')
  and myinitial <> myfinal

union 

select *
  from records  r
  where r.myinitial = '01' and r.myfinal = '01'
    and r.mydate =
        (select min(r2.mydate) from records r2
           where r2.myinitial='01' and r2.myfinal='01' and r2.id2 = r.id2)
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query. 
It will discard row where INITIAL=00 and FINAL=00 as you wanted to select only records with INITIAL = 01 or FINAL = 01 AND INITIAL = 01 AND FINAL = 01 with early date

```
SELECT ID1,ID2,DATE,INITIAL,FINAL FROM TEST1 WHERE ID1 NOT IN(SELECT ID1 FROM
(SELECT ID1,
  ID2,
  DATE,
  INITIAL,
  FINAL,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID2 ORDER BY DATE) rn
FROM TEST1
WHERE (INITIAL = '01'
AND FINAL    = '01')
) WHERE rn>1  ) AND (INITIAL != '00'OR FINAL!= '00');
```